# Visual Studio WPF Window shrinks on run?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio

*I was used to Windows Forms and non-resizeable windows when I posted this question, so I did not understand how to make content ajustable to the window. However, now that I understand how to use margins and other properties that allow for "responsive" windows, I highly recommend **not** to use this method. Use margins and alignment instead.*

---

I've been working with WPF.NET for quite a while now, but there is a problem that has been bugging me since I first started using it in Visual Studio. It seems that when I run my program, the windows shrinks by 10 pixels, in comparison to the designer display.

Here are some pictures to better explain my problem:

Designer mode display:

[image]

Actual window when ran:

[image]

---

This has only been occuring in WPF. It does not happen in Windows Forms. It has been happening in VS 2012 and VS 2013.

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Do you have size to content turned on? because it is apparent in the second picture that all the extra space below your two buttons and to the right of your text box is being cut. If you are looking for that specific look like you have in your designer I would suggest using Margins and padding instead of specific sizes to your controls.

Comment: I did not have size to content on. When I did turn it on though, it seemed to fix the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty new to all this, and this problem was very frustrating. I worked out that on run, the whole window shrank to the panel/grid size, losing about 10px from the panel/grid (x&y).
^^above didn't help much, no disrespect.
[I found this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/resources/894/automatically-resize-a-window-to-fit-content-in-wpf.aspx) by  XAML Designer(from 2010) which helped, maybe it will help you.

But basically, add:

```
    SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
```

(instead of ^Rohit Vats "d:DesignHeight="77" d:DesignWidth="294"") ..in the Window wrapper

Make sure all margins are set to desired value for the content. Worked perfectly for me.

Comment: This is what I actually did to fix my problem. However, in my case, I had to hardcode the grid's height and width. I'm not sure if that's what you meant by "make sure all margins are set to desired value for the content"

Comment: I heard you shouldn't hardcode height and width, but as I'm a beginner, I give myself a break. What I mean about margins, is when you do as I said in my answer, and you have grid on auto for H and W, then they should shrink to contents, so then the margin(s) of the content will have to be adjusted to push the grid away, to the desired outcome.

Answer (score 1):

`Design height and width might be set on your window` which is completely different from actual rendered height and width of control. Remove design heigh and width:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      mc:Ignorable="d"
      d:DesignHeight="77" d:DesignWidth="294"> <-- HERE

    <Grid>
        ...
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**On a side note you should totally avoid giving hard coded height and width to your control. Play with relative width and height instead OR simply let your containing panel decide height and width. Otherwise, on window resize your control won't resize per actual window dimensions.**

Comment: Designer size was not in my XAML, but I will follow your advice for future projects. Thanks for the tip!